# bash extract segments of a string and store in variables

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I want to convert the output from cppclean into cppcheck-like xml sections, such that:

`./bit_limits.cpp:25: static data 'bit_limits::max_name_length'`

becomes:

```
<error id="static data" msg="bit_limits::max_name_length">
    <location file="./bit_limits.cpp" line="25"/>
</error>
```

I started with some awk:

test code:

```
echo "./bit_limits.cpp:25: static data 'bit_limits::max_name_length'" > test
cat test.out | awk -F ":" '{print "<error id=\""$3"\""}
                           {print "msg=\""}{for(i=4;i<=NF;++i)print ":"$i}{print "\">"}
                           {print "<location file=\""$1"\" line=\""$2"\"/>"}
                           {print "</error>"}'
```

**Note:** to run this you need to put the `cat` command back into one line - I printed it over multi-lines for ease of reading.

**Explanation:**
I am using `awk` and delimiting by colon ":" - which splits the line into useful chunks which I try to construct into the XML:

- `{print "<error id=\""$3"\""}` - Extract the error ID part
- `{print "msg=\""}{for(i=4;i<=NF;++i)print ":"$i}{print "\">"}` - extract the message (replacing the missing colons, this is all the remaining sections
- `{print "<location file=\""$1"\" line=\""$2"\"/>"}` - extract the file and line, this part is easy since the colons line up nicely
- `{print "</error>"}` - finally print the end tag

This is close, but not quite right, it produces:

```
<error id=" static data 'bit_limits"
msg="
:
:max_name_length'
">
<location file="./bit_limits.cpp" line="25"/>
</error>
```

The *id* field should just be "static data" and the *msg* field should be "'bit_limits::max_name_length'", but other then that it is ok (I don't mind it being split of multi-lines at the moment - though I would prefer that awk did not print a new line each time.

**Update**
As @charlesduffy pointed out - for context - I want to do this in bash because I want to embed this code into a makefile (or just a normal bash script) for maximum portability (i.e. no need for python or other tools).

Comment: Note that generally speaking, using string-manipulation tools to parse or generate structured data is very bad practice. Use a real XML parser; there are lots of good ones you can invoke from bash (XMLStarlet, but it's also easy to just call a Python function), and that'll continue to work even if your data is written in a semantically-equivalent but textually-different format by the next version of the tools that generate it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for that sound advice : ). In this case I really want to embed this into a makefile. I don't want the user to have any pre-requisites (like python or whatever) just basic bash, sed, awk, etc... Its such a simple bit of XML

Comment: The usual approaches I'd use to efficiently read a single stream into several shell variables in a single pass don't *work* (or, rather, don't allow those shell variables to be persisted as distinct make variables) in the context of a makefile (where each action is run by a different shell instance), so that an answer should be useful in makefile context is an important bit of context to add. BTW, are you assigning `SHELL=bash`, or is your shell really `sh` (as make uses by default) and the question mistagged?

Comment: (Aside: Personally, I use [Nix](https://nixos.org/nix/) for assembling build systems; it does all the work of assembling dependencies for you, so with a Nix description, as opposed to a Makefile, you can have any dependencies you need -- Python modules or whole Python interpreters, JavaScript compilers, coreutils with a specific patch applied, a very specific bash release, *anything* -- provided by the build process itself in a fully reproducible manner).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yes this is true - I am using `bash` specifically for my makefiles. We have quite a good setup for our makefile, this is a minor tweak to it so that is why I would really like to stick with it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With bash and a regex:

```
x="./bit_limits.cpp:25: static data 'bit_limits::max_name_length'"
[[ $x =~ (.+):([0-9]+):\ (.+)\ \'(.+)\' ]]

declare -p BASH_REMATCH
```

Output:

```
declare -ar BASH_REMATCH='([0]="./bit_limits.cpp:25: static data '\''bit_limits::max_name_length'\''" [1]="./bit_limits.cpp" [2]="25" [3]="static data" [4]="bit_limits::max_name_length")'
```

The elements 1 to 4 in array BASH_REMATCH contain the searched strings.

From `man bash`:

> `BASH_REMATCH`: An array variable whose members are assigned by the `=~` binary operator to the `[[` conditional command. The element with index 0 is the portion of the string matching the entire regular expression. The  element with index n is the portion of the string matching the nth parenthesized subexpression. This variable is read-only.

Comment: can you break that down for me? - why is it in double `[`'s? I also assume that `BASH_REMATCH` is some special bash variable. IIRC things in brackets `(...)` become parameters? - so its looking for: 1. anything before a ":" 2. any number before a colon 3. then anything 4. then anything in single quotes... and all the outputs somehow magically get stored in an array called BASH_REMATCH! ... its pretty sweet, I think I am close to understanding it but some confirmation would be much appreciated : )

Comment: You're on the right track. I hope [this article](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-regular-expressions) will help you. With `[[ ... ]]` and `=~` it's possible to match a string (left side, with or without quotes) with a regex (right side and always without quotes).

Comment: that is so cool!... bye bye `sed`! I now have a copy of that script is my standard library, they should make that part of bash too :)

Answer (score 1):

Probably more complex than it needs to be:

```
awk '{
    split($1, file_line, ":")
    field = 2
    while(substr($field, 1, 1) != "'\''") {
        id = id " " $field
        ++field
    }
    id = substr(id, 2)
    while(field <= NF) {
        msg = msg " " $field
        ++field
    }
    msg = substr(msg, 3, length(msg) - 1)
    printf("<error id=\"%s\" msg=\"%s\">\n", id, msg)
    printf("    <location file=\"%s\" line=\"%s\">\n", file_line[1], file_line[2])
    print "</error>"
}' test.out
```

Comment: Better then my attempt - thanks, also learned a few more awk tricks : )